# does find command ignore anchors

Tags: regex, find

Let's say I have a file which has the path ./bar2.txt
and content of bar2.txt is

```
./bar2.txt
```

output of

```
grep "\bbar2\b" *
```

is

```
bar2.txt:./bar2.txt
```

as expected, wheres

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "\bbar2\b"
```

doesn't find anything.

I know I should change the regex to

```
".*/bar2.*"
```

since find looks for full path. So, does this mean that find ignores \b which specifies the word boundary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: might need to double-escape to `"\\bbar2\\b"` instead, since the first layer of backslashes would be stripped by the shell, before find is even invoked.

Comment: @MarcB tried but no luck. still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` and `find` will use different regular expression engines. Notably, POSIX regular expressions (which `find` uses) don't include "\b" as a word boundary, so it is the same as "b". On OSX, for instance, these have the same result:

`find . -regex '.*bar2.txt' -print`

and

`find . -regex '.*\bar2.txt' -print`

Double check the manpage to make sure that `-regex` is doing what you think. For my `find` the regular expression must match the entire filename, e.g. this doesn't find any files:

`find . -regex 'bar' -print`

but this one does:

`find . -regex '.*bar.*' -print`

Answer (score 0):

> However, what I am curious about is why it ignores `\b` which specifies word
>   boundary.

From my understanding `\b` is part of [**Perl regular expressions**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) and would not be available to `find`, as `find` does not support the Perl regextype as `grep` does.

Comment: I know it matches the filename. However, what I am curious  about is why it ignores \b which specifies word boundary. find always tries to match all path. However, by specifying the word boundary, I expected it to match only the word namely bar2 in the example I gave above.
I gave another example with grep and a regex to show how normally word boundary option works in grep. When results from both commands are compared, I can conclude \b is useless in find wheres it works fine with grep.

Comment: It's not ignoring \b. If a backslashed character isn't a regular expression meta-character, it's just the character itself. So, for a regex engine that doesn't know about word boundaries, '\b' and 'b' are the same expression.